# Remove invisible margin between div tags

Tags: html, css

for some reason I can't work out why it's doing this but my div tags have a small clear margin between each one making the div tags not but up to each other. Anyone have an idea where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
#content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
#header {
  background-color: #4C66A4;
}
#mainBody {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #4C66A4;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">
      <p>header</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainBody">
      <p>body</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That’s the default margin of the P elements. Go research _collapsing margins_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because browsers automatically add some margin before and after each `<p>` element, you need to set the `<p>` margin into **0** (zero) like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
#content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
#header {
  background-color: #4C66A4;
}
#mainBody {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #4C66A4;
}

#mainBody > p, #header > p, #footer > p {
  margin: 0; /*set all <p> elements inside the div id of #mainBody, #header and #footer into margin: 0*/ 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">
      <p>header</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainBody">
      <p>body</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the p elements default margin.

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add p {margin: 0px;}

```css
body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
#content {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
#header {
  background-color: #4C66A4;
}
#mainBody {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #4C66A4;
}
p {
margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">
      <p>header</p>
    </div>
    <div id="mainBody">
      <p>body</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```